# assign_attributes and ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app, I have decided to move some part of logic into the extra class called CategoryForm, which is dedicated to ActiveRecord `Category` class. Unfortunatelly as i pass params into `Category`, `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is raised.
Here is Category class:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :subcategories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories

end
```

CategoryForm class:

```
class CategoryForm

  attr_accessor :model

  def initialize(model, params = {})
    @model = model
    @model.assign_attributes(params)
    build_subcategories
  end  

  def save
    delete_empty_subcategories
    @model.save
  end  

  private

  def build_subcategories
    8.times { @model.subcategories.build}
  end

  def delete_empty_subcategories
    @model.subcategories.each { |subcategory| subcategory.delete if subacategory.empty?}
  end  

end
```

and the CategoryController fragment:

```
def create
    @category = Category.new
    @category_form = CategoryForm.new(@category, params[:category])
```

Error points into `@model.assign_attributes(params)` line, and as far as i understand it, my `Category` is unable to take params with subcategories. But on the other hand thats what `nested_attributes` are for... Any idea how to enable it correctly or what else is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are encountering is from [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), which was added in Rails 4. Try this code in your controller instead to filter the parameters through Strong Parameters:

```
def create
  @category = Category.new
  @category_form = CategoryForm.new(@category, category_params)
  # ...
end

private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit!
  end
```

Comment: thanks to your answer i realised i should've just used category_params and not params[:category], rails 3 habits:p

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answer, you can use in `rails 4` the  `protected_attributes` `gem` which let you work with `attr_accessible` as in `rails3`. And here's is a great [`railscast`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters) about the subject.
`

Comment: It's my understanding that the `protected_attributes` gem is provided for backwards compatibility, with strong parameters being the preferred default for new apps.